# Access USB Storage (OTG) in android 11

Tags: android, storage, file-permissions, android-external-storage

According to the documentation
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#operations-allowed-manage-external-storage, MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission grant access to root directory of the USB (OTG) drive.

```
val sm = application.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
val sv = sm.storageVolumes

sv.forEach{
    val curVolStats = StatFs(it.directory.toString())
}
```

The above code works well for Primary Storage and SDCARD. For the USB OTG drive, this return below error message:

```
2022-09-14 11:03:28.456 14141-14141/com.starsolutions.starfilemanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.starsolutions.starfilemanager, PID: 14141
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /mnt/media_rw/7ACF-B2AD
        at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:53)
        at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:43)
        at com.starsolutions.starfilemanager.data.ExplorerDataSource.getVolumes(ExplorerDataSource.kt:36)
        at com.starsolutions.starfilemanager.data.ExplorerRepository$getVolumeDetails$2.invokeSuspend(ExplorerRepository.kt:20)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@d17c76f, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Please help me where is my mistake?

Comment: You have not even told what your code should do. Nor which other paths you get that work well.

Comment: I want to get the free space available in each mounted volume. The above code works well for primary storage ('/storage/emulated/0') Storage and SDCARD (/storage/UUID).

Comment: Try File.exists() and File.canRead() on all three paths before you call your code.

Comment: File.exists() returns 'true' for primary and sdcard, and 'false' for USB. Can you please explain the reason happening like this?

Comment: Is it possible to access USB drive using direct file path or MediaStore API in android 11 with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: File.exusts() returns false as it is no file system path you got. All files permission has no effect. Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to get an uri for the drive. (not usable for StatFs().)

Comment: Thank you very much. That means The only way accessing USB drive is SAF. right?

Comment: Maybe. I dont know what the MediaStore would know about a just attached drive. Maybe after a while it makes an index. But i dont know. Experiment ;-)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75367630/how-to-access-files-on-an-attached-usb-flash-drive-android-12/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reported this in
[Google issue tracker.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246857526#comment9)
and got reply 'issue is fixed in S build'. Checked and its working android 12 and above