# How to access files on an attached USB flash drive [Android 12]

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, usb-drive

I am trying to read files from an attached USB flash drive, I have scoured through countless Stackoverflow questions and nothing is working.

I am able to detect when a USB is attached and I know that the USB is mounted under

```
/mnt/media_rw/
```

and I'm able to get this path using StorageManager but the system denies my app permission to read any files under that path even after adding all the needed permissions to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

According to the documentation "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission should give me access to all files on a storage device:

> The MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission grants the following:
> Read and write access to all files within shared storage.
> Access to the contents of the MediaStore.Files table.
>
> **Access to the root directory of both the USB on-the-go (OTG) drive and the SD card.**
>
> Write access to all internal storage directories⁠, except for /Android/data/, /sdcard/Android, and most   subdirectories of /sdcard/Android. This write access includes direct file path access.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

My question is very simple, all I want is a way to read files from an attached USB flash drive

Comment: "adding all the needed permissions to the manifest" -- there is no permission named `android.permission.USB_PERMISSION` in the Android SDK. "According to the documentation "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission should give me access to all files on a storage device" -- no, it does not. What you get is covered by [the Web page that you linked to](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#operations-allowed-manage-external-storage), and your quoted passage does not claim that you get "access to all files on a storage device".

Comment: Beyond that, I do not think that `/mnt/media_rw/` is going to be useful for you, even if you [follow all the instructions for using `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access). You need to find the right root path for the removable storage device. Try using `StorageManager` and `StorageVolume`, particularly [`getDirectory()` on `StorageVolume`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume?hl=en#getDirectory()), to see if you get a different location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used that permission because it was mentioned as a solution in a different thread so I was trying it out and regarding the document what does "access to the root directory of both the USB on-the-go (OTG) drive and the SD card" mean then? Also, it mentions that File managers apps are one use case of apps that request this permission and most of these apps are able to show you files from a connected USB flash drive and you are able to read/write to them. Is their something that I am misunderstanding/missing?

Comment: getDirectory() is what I used to get that path

Comment: "regarding the document what does "access to the root directory of both the USB on-the-go (OTG) drive and the SD card" mean then?" -- sorry, I misread your original comment and thought you were expecting access to the entire filesystem. "getDirectory() is what I used to get that path" -- that's interesting; I would have expected something not in `/mnt/`. Did you manually grant the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for your app via the Settings app? Can you perhaps add a [mcve] showing how you are trying to read files?

Comment: Also, can a pre-installed file manager access the USB drive? Or, are you able to use `getExternalFilesDirs()` on `Context` to access app-specific storage on the USB drive? The latter isn't what you are seeking, but it might help determine if your issue is somehow tied to the way Android is interacting with that USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

You should let the user choose the usb drive with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

After that you can browse the whole drive and have access to all files.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have newer devices, and the Android emulator does not provide an easy way to simulate USB storage, so I ran some tests with two Android 11 devices and an old one with Android 8. The results: Unfortunately USB storage is not generally available via the standard file system. Instead, Google obviously forces you to use its proprietary *Storage Access Framework* (as mentioned in blackapps' answer). Note that SAF causes an acceleration factor of about 1/100, compared to standard file operations, and is not available at all for native code (C/C++/Assembler).

In particular my **LG** Android 11 device **does provide** file access via /storage/XXXX-XXXX. The **Samsung** device does **not**. Also the Android 8 device does not.

If you want to test yourself, run "adb shell" or run Termux on your device and execute the "mount" command. Grep for "/mnt/media_rw/" to see which mass storages are available and for "/storage/" to see which of them are accessible via file system. If you have an SD card, you should see "/storage/emulated/0" for internal memory and some "/storage/YYYY-YYYY" for your SD card. If there is another "/storage/XXXX-XXXX", this is your OTG memory. Maybe you must avoid Samsung. I encourage everybody to test this functionality on his or her own devices.

Generally I have the impression that the file access concept in Android is somewhat suboptimal and even more suboptimal since Android 11, especially for programming.